# check whether php mysql update was successful or not

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code. I am trying to update my password. How can I check whether the update was successful or not?

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','ashwinma_search');
define('PASS','bbbbb');
define('DB','aaaaa');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
{
$email=$_GET['email'];
$password=$_GET['password'];

$qry_check="UPDATE tb_login SET password='$password' where email='$email'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$qry_check);
 if(<what should i add here ?>){ 
 echo "sucess";
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: if($res) { echo "success"; }

Answer (score 2):

> *"How can I check whether the update was successful or not?"*
>   *"`if(<what should i add here ?>){`"*

You would use and best to use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) for truthness, and checking for errors on the query if it fails.

I.e.:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) ) {
    echo "sucess";
}

else {
  echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

Note: It appears that you may be storing plain text passwords. If this is the case, it is unsafe. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

You're also open to an sql injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement